# Which root paths (e.g., /lib) can never be symlinks?

Tags: root, symbolic-link

VBox suggests an extremely inadequate default size for its root partition, so I had to create and mount a more realistic `/dev/sdb1` to do anything useful.  Despite that, `/` (`/dev/sda1`) is 96% full, and `/usr` appears to be by far the largest consumer, causing me to ^C out of `du -s /usr`.

My first mistake was to `sudo mv /lib /home/jerry/sdb1/root_lib` with the intention of following this with `ln -s /home/jerry/sdb1/root_lib /lib`, only to find that nothing in `/bin` works without `/lib`!

I am in the process of repairing this by mounting both virtual disks on a different device and copying the path back to its original location (even if not necessarily to the original clusters, as boot code might require).  Obviously, even if I did create a symlink while it's not bootably mounted, it's unlikely the system could process a symlink without `/lib` as an absolute path!

Before I waste my time and patience on another misguided experiment, is either `/usr` itself or any of its more bloated subdirectories, safe to move to another partition and instantiate as a symlink?  :D

Answer (score 1):

In archlinux, `/bin`, `/lib`, `lib64`, `/sbin` are all symlinks and this works fine.

I don't see why it's not working with you. You should have made the symlinks while the system was not running, ie by mounting the filesystem in a live session or similar

Also, if you use partitions and mount them, then I don't see why you need to use symlinks at all? For example, you could copy only the content of `/lib/*` into your new partition and mount it under `/lib` with `/lib` directory still on your root partition. That way, there is no need for symlinks.

Comment: I'll try creating a third partition to mount for this purpose.  /dev/sdb1 is already mounted and used for all my workspaces, etc., so using that solely for system files isn't an option.  Yeah, I guess doing it while the VM was up was a bad idea, and I panicked until it occurred to me to make the vhd files available to another VM for repair.  Yes, mounting would be a much safer alternative, since it is part of the boot process, while I'm not so certain about the activation of symlinks.  Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you know sudo is in /usr/bin, and even on a one-user machine created by me, I don't have the root password?  So I guess that means it's either /usr/share or /usr/src that will have to be the mount point!